# JSON Values extends another JSON values

Tags: java, json

My Json structure is like

```
main = {
        "hideIds1":["id1","id2","id3","id4"],
        "hideIds2":["id11","id12","id13","id14"], 
        "maindHides1":["hideIds1","id7","id9"]
        "maindHides2":["hideIds1","hideIds2","id14","id18"]
    }
```

Looks "mainHides1" is extends all the values of "hideIds1".When i iterate "mainHides1" i have to check the key is having the values or not in the main JsonObject.In this iteration, first value becomes true but for other ids it wont need.

What i am expect here is when i access the "maindHides1" values it becomes like ["id1","id2","id3","id4","id7","id9"]. Will json do it automatically something like extends or i have to do it manually in program?

Or anyother samrtway to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GSON` library and caste your `JSON` into java `object`.Once you have java object with you you can do your required task.

Answer (score 1):

For the option of manual, you can create your own hashset with keys from JSON and what you can do is that while adding values you can cross check if they are equal to any current key values. if yes then you can add its values in internal loop to the value set.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON itself it is not possible but I suggest using something like [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) and just create your models as you want, It will be something like that:

```
interface IMainModel {
    IDs: array;
}
var donut: IHides1Model = {
    main: IMainModel,
    IDs: array
};
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is pure type construction it is not a class,library or framework.
You would need to make this extension manually.